# Grafana: X-Y chart. How to set Series names dynamically

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have the following chart
[image]
build by

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (kpi, build_id)
   kpi as KPI,
   build_id AS BUILD_ID, 
   average_time AS AVERAGE_TIME
   FROM <MY_TABLE> WHERE kpi IN (${kpi});
```

where `${kpi}` is multi-value variable that contains `kpi` values selected by user from drop-down menu.

I try to do: Override --> Fields with name: "kpi (base field name)" --> Add property: Standard options: Display name: `${__series.name}`, but still `Series 1`, `Series 2`... displayed as labels for chart lines

How to set `kpi` name to corresponding chart instead of `Series N`?